# JQuery Ajax Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the simple code that should display Ajax loading animation when form is submitted:

```
var init = function() {
    $("form").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
        $("#comments_loading").show();
    });

    $("form").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
        $("#comments_loading").hide();
    });
};

$(document).load(init);
```

It's purpose is to display the loading animation on Ajax request.  It works perfectly, but... only for the first form submit!!! Any suggestions why/how can this be addressed can be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ajax is sent via some framework helper I use. In essence it is very simple ajax form submit which triggers a html replace.  Perhaps load event is not getting tiggered? Wonder what else I can use...

Comment: See if it is - throw a console.log("load triggered") in the beginning of your init function and watch the console to see if it is being fired

Comment: Yep the load event happens once. That explains it. Are there are any other events that I can use for triggering the binding?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `.on` instead. Same syntax, different method name:

```
$("form").on('ajax:complete', function() {
    $("#comments_loading").hide();
});
```

Because I am assuming that your ajax loaded form is not the exact same element as your original form

Comment: You should post your ajax call